# Sticky toolbar becomes transparent when there is a list as content

Tags: css

I have tried reproduce the bug [here](https://codepen.io/bardoman/pen/wvgZNBd) but it didn't happen.
The problem i have is that the sticky header (which in my real app is a simple div as a toolbar) becomes transparent only when it hovers a list (ul or ol) ([demo](https://i.imgur.com/K0rMHcj.gif))

Anyone has a clue why this happen and how to prevent it ?

I have tried to force the opacity by setting it to 1 and i even tried a background-image besides of a background-color

```
.menubar {
    background-color: #f8f8f8 !important;
    height: -moz-fit-content;
    height: fit-content;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 1px;
    position: sticky;
    bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-image: url(https://www.fapceramiche.com/media/products/images/article/generated_fap_sheer_2020_beige_matt_R10_90x90_002_fPB0_hr.jpg.520x516_q85_crop_upscale.jpg);
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a z-index with a large number like so, `z-index: 100;`